# If $A+B=AB$ then $AB=BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was doing the problem $$ A+B=AB\implies AB=BA. $$

$AB=BA$ means they're invertible, but I can't figure out how to show that $A+B=AB$ implies invertibility.

Comment: Note that $AB=BA$ is not the same, nor does it imply, that $A,B$ are invertible.

Comment: The correct name of "$AB=BA$" is "$A$ and $B$ *commute*". Invertibility is a different property (namely, a matrix $A$ is invertible if $A^{-1}$ exists).

Comment: @Coffeemath Why not same

Comment: If A and B are equal, where each has rows [0,1],[0,0] then these aren't invertible, even though AB=BA.

Comment: Just to say, suppose $A$ and $B$ are both the zero matrix.  Then of course $A+B=AB=BA$ but neither $A$ nor $B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Consider the expression $$(A-\mathbb 1)(B-\mathbb 1)=AB-A-B+\mathbb 1=\mathbb 1$$

Thus $(A-\mathbb 1)$ and $(B-\mathbb 1)$ are inverse to each other, whence $$\mathbb 1= (B-\mathbb 1)(A-\mathbb 1)=BA - A - B + \mathbb 1$$

It follows that $$BA=A+B=AB$$ and we are done.

Note:  here $\mathbb 1$ denotes the appropriate identity matrix.

Comment: if $ a * b =e$ then $b*a=e$ iff $a$ and $b$ are elements of a group and $e$ is the identity element of that group . Are $X=(A-1)$ and $Y=(B-1)$elements of any group with identity $1$  ?

Comment: If yes, then please explain!

Comment: Yes, $X,Y$ are invertible matrices and these form a group.

Comment: but how ? can you prove that $X$ and $Y$ are invertible with the condition $A+B=AB$

Comment: @Abhishek  I proved they were invertible by exhibiting inverses.  Specifically, I showed that $XY=\mathbb 1$.  If nothing else, that equation shows that $\det X \times \det Y =1\neq 0$ so both $X,Y$ have to be invertible,

Comment: can we use $I$ insted of $1$ ?

Comment: @TheStudent  Sure, it's just notation.

Comment: @lulu, do we have any requirement for =(−)(−) to hold? OP's question doesn't make any assumptions on the field or group of  and  objects. I cannot understand why  (−)(−)=  would imply (−)(−) =. Basically, I'm missing why "Thus (−) and (−) are inverse to each other, whence". Could you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: In a group, left inverses coincide with right inverses, see, e.g., [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Left_Inverse_for_All_is_Right_Inverse) Invertible matrices form a group.  I am assuming that these are matrices over a field, haven't thought about generalizations (which presumably exist).

Answer (score 3):

Start with equation:
$$A+B=AB$$
replace $B$ with $(B - I) + I$ in left side
$$A+(B - I) + I =AB$$
$$I =AB - A - (B - I)$$
$$I =A(B - I) - (B - I)$$
$$I =(A - I)(B - I)$$
the inverse matrix of $(B - I)$ is $(A - I)$, so $(B - I)$ is invertible. Then the rest follows as in previous answer by @lulu

Comment: $XY=0$ doesn't mean either $X$ or $Y$ is zero when $X$ and $Y$ are matrices. A counter example: $X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @obareey thanks, I have re-edited