# Sum of two matrices equals product; prove that the matrices commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B$ be square real matrices of the same size such that $A+B=AB$. Show that $AB=BA$.

I have got the result for invertible matrices, but what about non-invertible ones?

Comment: From the given condition I am getting (A+B)=BA

Comment: By using invertibility

Comment: This does NOT follow.  We aren't merely defining $AB=A+B$ ... it just happens that they are equal. This is not a matter of mere symbol manipulation.

Comment: Nandita , you've got your answer , I think , If you've any doubt you may comment .

Comment: Ok thanks  but can you please explain the fact that if A and B are taken to be invertible then what will happen

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2242650/516174 , In this answer $A$ and $B$ are general matrices they can be singular or non-singular. Also, see my comments below this answer .