# If $A+B = AB$ then proving that $AB = BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Even though this has been asked before in main site [If $A+B=AB$ then $AB=BA$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242629/if-ab-ab-then-ab-ba), still I had a query?

If $A,B$ are both $n \times n$ matrix and the entries are from $\Bbb{R}$. If it satisfies $A+B = AB$, then can we say that $A$ and $B$ commute? that is $AB = BA$ ?

I thought of this that as we are given the rule $A+B = AB$, so that also implies that $B+A =BA$ just interchanging the roles of $A$ and $B$? from which we get $AB = BA$ hence $A$ and $B$ commute. Any flaw in this?

How do we approach this problem?

Comment: it is not given that $X+Y=XY$ for *all* matrices, so that you can plug in $A$ and $B$ as you wish. It is only given that $A+B=AB$ for particular matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $\boldsymbol A, \boldsymbol B$ are *fixed* here, the symmetry might not be applicable here.

Comment: $A+B=AB$ is not an identity so we can't change the roles of $A$ and $B$ and arrive at another correct equation. For example if you are solving $2x+3y=0$, then we can't interchange $x$ and $y$ and derive another equation $2y+3x=0$.

Comment: Great comments!! thank you :)

Comment: I don't see where this question differs from the linked question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The difference, I think, is that the OP is asking whether a certain specific proof is valid ($A+B=AB$ implies $BA=B+A=A+B=AB$.)

Comment: @David, OK, well I guess that's been answered in the comments, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments, especially Marco's, identify the fundamental flaw in the reasoning.  You can interchange symmetrically equivalent variables only in an identity.  Here the relevant identity is actually a logical expression:

$(A-I)(B-I)=I\implies (B-I)(A-I)=I$

*That* is where you can interchange the symetrically equivalent variables.

Incidentally, the original claim is not really true for all pairs of matrices satisfying the hypothesis.  For *finite* order matrices, yes; but consider the infinite order matrices defined thusly, for all natural numbers $i, j$:

$A_{i,i}=A_{i,i+1}=1, A_{i,j}=0 \text{ otherwise}$

$B=A^t$

Then $AB=A+B$ but $BA\ne AB$. We get $(AB)_{1,1}=2$ but $(BA)_{1,1}=1$.  Delving a little bit deeper, we find that $(A-I)(B-I)=I$ but $(B-I)(A-I)\ne I$ due to the latter having $0$ rather than $1$ in the $(1,1)$ position.  The identity on which a proper proof is based, does not generally hold for infinite order matrices, and the claim goes with it.